# What is customer focus testing and how do I implement it?

Tags: test-management

I am working in a project as a tester in which I have to do the Customer Focus Test (CFT). But I have no idea on how to do a CFT. Can anybody explain me?

Comment: Have you asked your manager (or assigned you the CFT role) what *they* think CFT means?

Answer (score 7):

The features of many software projects are based on customer stories. Stories describe a typical or target customer and describe how that person uses various features of the software to help them perform some desired task. It is also common for these user stories to have a persona (e.g. Jeremy is at a sporting event and uses his phone to take a picture, upload the picture to facebook and twitter with captions, blah, blah, blah.)

Customer focused testing is generally when the tester takes on the persona of a customer described by one or more user stories.

CFT describes a goal, but leaves it up to the imagination of the tester as to how to achieve that goal. It also is great at testing the "look and feel," and the "real experience."

I think where CFT sometimes falls short is that the stories tend to be rather short focused scenarios and don't portray a picture of a "day in the life" of that persona, and may not hit edge cases very well.

Comment: So is it Customer Focused Testing? Or Customer Focus Testing?

Comment: +1 This is a great answer! You need to put yourself in the shoes of the customer to do Customer Focused Testing. It is beyond just verifying what's given in the spec.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what is your product primary gole? 
Once you release your product for what reason your customer going to use it?
How your customer going to use it? 
What can be the client environment(different OS/RAM, for web application different browsers etc) in which you product will be installed and will be executed?
Do you know what will be the traffic of your product? If yes then create similar scenario and do a proper planning for performance test.

I think if you know above answers then it will be easy for you to do customer focus testing.

Answer (score 1):

Besides knowing what CFT is. I would highly recommend you speak with your manager about this. It is important to know what they think it is and what they would like for you to do. It doesn't matter if you do the right thing and then find out they meant something else.

CFT mostly revolves around user scenarios. Instead of test cases (atomic ones at that), use scenarios that perform a particular task from a user/customer's perspective. For example, if your product was the paint tool that ships with windows, one scenario could be print screen, paste and then save file. This as opposed to 1 test case that tests file saves, another one that tests copy pasting to canvas and so on. This gives you an amazing advantage of verifying if a scenario works completely. Your product might work in pieces but what if it is a pain to complete simple tasks that the user/customer would perform on a daily basis?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what the goals are of this Customer Focus Testing - maybe they can help you decide  on a "good enough" approach?

Comment: As I am a newbie to this CFT,I asked about that in here.

Comment: Ok - do you know what the goals of testing are for your project?